# parsing large xml file with python

Tags: python, parsing, xml-parsing

xml file example:

```
<header>
<name>name</name>

<items>

<item>
<title>title</title>
<add>add</add>
</item>

<item>
<title>title</title>
<add>add</add>
</item>

</items>
</header>
```

I would like to parse the info into groups broken up by each header and subgroup item:

xml parse too:

```
name
----title
----add

----title
----add

next header

name
----tile
----add
----etc
----etc
```

if someone could post an example, preferable with elem tree iterparse
its a large xml file...

my example that doesn't work is...

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
infile = open("c:/1.xml", 'r')
context = etree.iterparse(infile, events=("start", "end"))

for event, element in context:
    if event == "end":
        if element.tag == "header":
            print element.findtext('name')
        elif element.tag == "item":
            print element.findtext('title')
            print element.findtext('add')
```

Comment: You need to start by reading the documentation and trying to solve the problem on your own, then come back and show us what you've tried and where it's failing.

Comment: You should take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html (Its part of python)

Comment: To further larsks comment, What are you trying to parse it into? do you just want it to print, do you want to store as a string, should it be a dictionary of lists...

Comment: @ larsks - I have tried to do it... figured no need to post my code since its a mess and doesn't work...

Comment: @ Chris, just a print is fine... I would have no problems using it from that point... my problem is parsing the groups...

Comment: @user2689866 This is a very simple problem to solve. We don't have time to write code for you (everyone one is probably at work sparing some time) but rather we can answer specific questions about problem.

Comment: changed question to include example code, which doesn't work... @enginefree sure it may be simple to someone who knows... but i'm learning python and don't see why my code doesn't work...

Comment: Just add `--` when you print your element (as you go down the hierarchy), that would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

So, nice and simply, with the infile you provided:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

for event, element in etree.iterparse("C:/1.xml"):
    if element.tag == "name":
        print element.text
    elif element.tag in ["title", "add"]:
        print "---" + element.text
```

this gives output:

```
name
----title
----add
----title
----add
```

I guess if you wanted a spacer between headers you'd just:

```
if element.tag == "header":
    print "\n"
```

Comment: ...doesn't work, at least for python 2.7 - the entire file is loaded still.